# Send email to different email depending on taxonomy term

Tags: 8, emails

This was fairly simple to do in D7 and is a common request. How would I send an email to a different email address depending on a taxonomy term chosen from a dropdown box on the contact form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you did it in D7, but [hook_mail_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/8.2.x) is my preferred solution. And in [hook_form_contact_site_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.2.x) i would add taxonomy term reference field to the contact form.

> This still works in D8

Code would look like this in your custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail_alter().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_mail_alter(&$message) {

  if ($message['id'] == 'contact_page_mail') {

    $tid = $message['params']['your_form_field'];
    if (!empty($tid) && $tid > 0) {
      // $tid to determine the address ?!
      $message['to'] = 'your@emai.l';
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Isn't `contact_page_copy` the mail that should be sent to me after checking the `Send me a copy` box? Are you sure you should change the `$message['to']` for that mail as well?

Comment: no true .. this was a left over ... i removed it.